# How do I write a clean conditional statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

This may be a dumb question but what is an easy way to write a clean condition statement, for example lets say if I have a conditional statement where I only want it to happen before a block of code if it meets the requirement and if it doesn't then I want it to happen after the block of code. But it must happen in that order

**EDIT**

This code is NOT broken.. I was simply asking if there was a better way of structuring this conditional statement and I found out that putting the //random code in a helper method and combining the two if's into an else if would solve it. See my answer below.

```
if(number === 250){
    // sameMethod()
}

//random code

if(number !== 250){
    // sameMethod()
}
```

**Solution**

```
function helper() {
    //random code
}

if(number !== 250){
    helper()
    // same code
} else {
    // same code
    helper()
}
```

Comment: please tag only the relevant language, javascript and java are not the same

Comment: why not put the random code into a method, then if (number ==250) { sameMethod(); randomCode(); }else { randomMethod(); sameMethod(); } ?

Comment: @YHStan yeah that would make more sense, i guess I was thinking too lazily

Comment: @Stultuske Those are the two languages that I don't mind seeing when answering the question since they both using the same structure and I am familiar with it.

Comment: @DaCoda they don't use the same structures. that's the whole point

Comment: @YHStan if he does that, the randomCode(); becomes part of the conditional blocks. The second condition is based on the outcome of that random block, so the random block must be executed before you know whether the second condition is true/false. You would be altering the flow if you did that

Comment: @DaCoda I deleted my 'not so clear' earlier comment, I hope my comment to YHStan explains a bit more clear why not to resolve it like that.

Comment: @Stultuske I see... Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Perhaps `number === 250 ? (sameMethod(), randomCode()) : (randomCode(), sameMethod());`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(number == 250){
    // sameMethod()
}

//random code

if(number != 250){
    // sameMethod()
}
```

For this, and based on the information at hand, I would recommend keeping the code as is. The way you have written this code, an if-else block would have a serious impact on the flow of your application.

Assume that randomCode is a method call, which performs the next operation:

```
function randomCode() {
  this.number += 5;
}
```

and you start the code with the state of your application having the value of number as 245.

```
if ( number == 250 ) { // conditions 245 == 250 evaluates to false
  // sameMethod -> will not be executed
}

randomCode(); // increases the value of number with 5

if ( number != 250 ) { // condition 250 != 250 evaluates to false
  // sameMethod -> will not be executed
}
```

Just slapping an if-else, like this:

```
if ( number == 250 ) { // condition 245 == 250 evaluates to false
  // sameMethod
} else {
  randomCode();
  // sameMethod -> here it will be executed, even though number now is 250. Change in behaviour
}
```

So, there are two things to consider: either the example code you posted was the correct flow, making it correct (but might end up in executing sameMethod twice, or not at all, since the value of number could be altered in the randomCode part, or both sameMethod and randomCode have to be executed (exactly) once, depending on that condition.

If so, the original (pseudo?) code was faultive, but the result would indeed come to:

```
if ( number == 250 ) {
  sameMethod();
  randomCode();
} else {
  randomCode();
  sameMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where monads and all that jazz show their ugly mugs.

Assuming you are talking about java, you could for example write a `runSequentially` method that results in letting you write:

```
   runSequentially(() -> sameMethod(), () -> {
        // random code
   }, number != 250);
```

Where runSequentially will first run the first Runnable, then the second Runnable - unless the condition is false, in which case it runs the second, then the first.

In java, this is not, however, local mutable variable, checked exception, and control flow transparent which are sufficient downsides that I'm not sure this is a good idea. Especially considering that apparently execution order matters which usually suggests mutating state. But, if you insist, it'd be something like:

```
public static void runSequentially(Runnable a, Runnable b, boolean flipOrder) {
    if (flipOrder) { b.run(); a.run(); }
    else { a.run(); b.run(); }
}
```

Javascript is a lot more laissez-faire (and a totally different language; did you tag it because perhaps you were unaware that 'java' and 'javascript' are completely unrelated? It's a common mistake - in that case, disregard this bit), and doesn't suffer from the transparency issues as much. Javascript has no checked exceptions, javascript lets you mutate outer state (there are some WTFs in javascript-the-language about this, but that's a separate issue). The biggest issue is control flow (you can't as easily break/continue loops in the 'outer' code from within these closures).

Going back to java for a moment, using lambdas (closures) in contexts where:

- The lambda is run 'in-line', that is, you pass the lambda to some method, and once that method returns, the lambda is 'forgotten about' by said method: That method did not store the lambda in a field, did not pass it to another thread, did not pass it to other code that is going to store it in a field or pass it to another thread).
- The code in the lambda is not designed 'functional style' (e.g. it mutates state or does a bunch of I/O), then

you're probably messing up. Lambdas really suck in that environment, those transparency issues are grating then. Note that if the lambda does 'travel' (is stored / moved to another thread), that lack of transparency is in fact a great thing because those 3 'transparencies' become bizarre braintwisters - best to just not allow them.

That's why I recommend against this, if you're writing java. But now you know how one would.

Comment: Is it possible for it to after running randomMethod() to check if the number != 250 before deciding whether or not to run sameMethod()? The above method order of running randomMethod() and sameMethod seems to depend on the initial check of number

Comment: @rzwitserloot you would be changing the flow and functionality if you did, though. the else block isn't based on originalIf is false, it's based on a new condition after randomCode has been executed AFTER the first if block

Comment: The _question_ strongly implies that this answer is what they wanted, and that the snippet shown in the question is simply their take on how to get there; the fact that their take would 'break' if the `number` value changes is a problem with their snippet, not a representation of their needs. The same concept (lambdas and a custom method with the logic that connects them and the predicate) can be used to solve what Stultukse and YHStan seem to want, with the same 'but.. do not do that' caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice, I should've been more clear about the language since I thought this was a fairly simple solution that might work in both Java and Javascript. I ended up just putting the "random code" in a helper function.

```
function helper() {
    //random code
}

if(number !== 250){
    helper()
    // same code
} else {
    // same code
    helper()
}
```

Basically the idea was that, the order of which block of code that gets executed mattered depending on a fixed variable. It was messy without a helper function due to duplicated code so this simple solution fixed it. Let me know if you guys think of a more clever way! Thanks

Comment: I hope you understand that by doing so, you may have seriously changed the functionality of the original code?

Comment: @Stultuske It did not change the functionality of the original code. I was implementing a grid chart for images. If I add images to a row and the last image I added surpassed the row's width by lets say 50 pixels, then I want to create a new row and add the image to that new row. If it does not surpass that row's width by 50 pixels but say 35 pixels. I want to keep that image in the row and THEN create a new row. It was confusing but I wanted to ask the question with simple words. It essential describes the same thing.

Comment: maybe not that of the code you have in your project, but it does change the functionality compared to the code snippet you've shown in your question.